# Why did Yoda consider himself defeated after falling down?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

In the end of *Revenge of the Sith*, Yoda and Palpatine fought and the fight ended when they got blown out by a Force blast. Although Palpatine was able to catch a railing, Yoda couldn't and he fell to his doom.

But, the thing is: gravity barely matters in a world of the Force. So, I don't think Yoda's fall hit him that hard that he couldn't fight again.

Why didn't he jump up again to go after Palpatine?

Comment: If we apply the conclusions drawn by Professor Plinkett, we can say that if Palpatine and Yoda were evenly matched in terms of the Force, then the deciding factor would be who is physically better suited to combat.  Yoda is a 2 foot tall puppet with a tiny reach and is really old.  Palpatine is an elderly man, but still a fully sized human with a far greater reach.

Answer (score 8):

Yoda was already beaten by that point. Despite seemingly able to hold up to Darth Sidious at first he was put on the defense during the whole fight. And that despite him giving himself over to the force fully and using it as much as he could.

He still tried to press on, but was weakening visibly more and more during the fight. _In the novel it is explained that he saw that he was fighting the wrong war the whole time......that he tried (and the jedi order itself tried) to reenact the last war while the sith had....adapted and became something else, something more. Something he (and they) could not beat.

When Yoda fell he on purpose did not try to come up again and instead fled as he already saw (even in the film) that he was not able to overcome the dark lord of the sith. Soemthing / someone else was needed for that. Someone trained differently than himself and Obi Wan.

Answer (score 3):

Yoda was clearly exhausted and could not use Force properly, he even could not stop himself from falling, something average Jedi knight would do with relative ease. He panted heavily while fleeing trough tunnels, and he didn't look very well in a scene with Organa. He lost his lightsaber, and clones were coming, he didn't have means to deflect their shots. Finally, in novelization he "understood" that he cannot beat Sidious because "Sith have evolved" and similar drivel. I find this explanation pretty thin, because one moment of luck separated both of them (Yoda and Palpatine) from decapitating their opponent. But there you have it.

Comment: don't forget obi wan.  There is no luck only the will of the force.

Comment: @Thomas That would make whole SW universe fatalistic and pre-determined, and I don't think that was intention.

Comment: It is still so that the Jedi mention it a few times (especially obi wan). In their "religion" it is just so.

Comment: Yoda didn't lose his lightsaber..

Comment: @SachinStark So what happened at 3:21 in the clip ? ;)

Comment: After seeing the clip I remembered that a question I always had is why he was taken by surprise by the lightning